# How can I implement a channel logic to my WebSocket including events where I can bind to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I am currently facing a very big challenge: My own WebSocket server. I have already programmed the authentication and all the details so that the server runs and handles requests, but currently I'm stuck with the actual logic.

I have written a class in JavaScript for this, which should be called as follows:

```
let token       = "ABC",
    myWebSocketClient = new MyWebSocketClient(token);

myWebSocketClient.subscribe("cWhFVEtlOENNM0VwNmlrUlBmOVF1UT09").bind("create_browser_push", function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The idea is that I can subscribe to a special channel with `.subscribe()` and listen to a special event in it with `.bind()`. For that I've found this file as my orientation but this is a bit to much for me and my needs:

https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js/blob/0d718adf06566766e0f544d74565d2ff3dcc0ff8/src/core/pusher.ts#L254

My `MyWebSocketClient` class looks like this

```
class MyWebSocketClient {
    constructor(token) {
        this.url   = "ws://localhost:8181";
        this.token = token;

        this.connect();
    }

    connect() {
        let self = this,
            ws   = new WebSocket(self.url);

        ws.onopen = function () {
            let authMsg = {
                type: "authenticate",
                payload: {token: self.token}
            };

            ws.send(JSON.stringify(authMsg));
        };
    }

    subscribe(channelName) {

    }

    bind(eventName) {

    }
}
```

My client connects and authenticates with my `WebSocket Server` in `NodeJS` which makes me really happy. This is simple but works:

```
const WebSocket  = require('ws').Server;
const express    = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const wss = new WebSocket({
    server: app.listen(8181)
});

let wsObj = null;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

wss.on('connection', ws => {
    wsObj = ws;

    ws.on('message', toEvent).on('authenticate', function (data) {
        const receivedToken = data.token;

        if (!receivedToken || receivedToken === '') {
            return ws.close(4000, 'Bad Request');
        }

        verifyToken(receivedToken).then(() => {
            //User is authenticated and connected
        }).catch((err) => {
            if (err === 401) {
                return ws.close(4010, 'Unauthorized');
            } else {
                return ws.close(5000, 'Internal Server Error');
            }
        });
    });
});

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    const receivedToken = req.query.token;

    if (!receivedToken || receivedToken === '') {
        return res.sendStatus(400).end();
    }

    verifyToken(receivedToken).then(() => {
        //Request is valid and can be handled / maybe we need the wsObj here

        console.log(req.body);
        //Result of a request:

        //{
        //    name: 'create_browser_push', <- The event
        //    data: 'null', <- Should be sent back to the client to be accessible over the "response" parameter
        //    channels: [ 'cWhFVEtlOENNM0VwNmlrUlBmOVF1UT09' ]
        //}

    }).catch(() => {
        return res.sendStatus(401).end();
    });
});

function toEvent(message) {
    try {
        const event = JSON.parse(message);

        this.emit(event.type, event.payload);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Not an event: ', err);
    }
}

function verifyToken(token) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (token === 'ABC') {
            resolve();
        } else {
            reject(401);
        }
    });
}
```

Does someone has an idea how I can get this done a simple way? So that when I sent something from the backend, that the user connected to the channel and bindet to the event get's the notification?

And is it possible somehow that the server knows which client subscribed to a specific channel/event so that I don't need to check it on the client side (if this makes sense)?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

For each connected client on `connection` event call:

1. Create an unique identifier (ID) for the connection;
2. Store its socket object into a global object.

For each `subscribe` event call:

1. Store the connection ID to a global object keeping track of all channels subscriptions.

So when publishing data to a channel:

1. Filter all active connections IDs subscribed to that channel;
2. Get all connection objects for those IDs;
3. Use the connection objects to send the message.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So should I not create the two methods on the client site (subscribe/bind)? I'm not fully understanding it but basically I understand your idea!

Comment: This connection and subscription management has to be done by the server itself. The client has only to listen to a `message` event. Also remember to update these objects when the connection breaks or a client disconnects.

Comment: Do you think it's a good way generating the UUID on the server site by sending the id as an answer for a successful authentication? I would save the id in a `this.clientId` variable or something like this to use it for the subscriptions if this is a good way. Otherwise I'm not sure. What if the client is gone instantly after sending the authentication message? So many questions haha

Comment: I think this connection UUID might be specific for server's connection and subscription management. Sure you can send it to the client as a authentication response, but for what? Your client shall not receive messages for channels which they are not subscribed for. When the client is gone instantly after sending the authentication message, you'll get a `close` event and can use it to update the connections and subscriptions objects in the server.

Comment: Okay thanks. So I'll generate the UUID on the client site after the page loaded. And for the rest: I hope I get this done. My idea was to create an object with all subscriptions and events when the page loads. After that my plan was to sent this obj to the server with the UUID (Or would you sent each single event instead of the object with all events?). At the server I'll also create an obj with all clients, the `ws` event (as a reference)  and the subscription object. When a new request comes in I'll loop over my clients obj and sent the message to all clients subscribed.

Comment: Hey Mr. Koch, I've did it and it's working awesome! But it's too complicated to write it down here. Maybe if someone asks for the solution I'll take some hours for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have limited JavaScript experience as all my projects are mainly Python/Django but I really just research JavaScript were its needed.  So i'm using this script which passes activity to my notifications for example a new like, comment, message etc.  Also, I think you can generate a websocket by running `npm run browserify`.  Have a look at this code here that i have in my project.  Hope you can take something from it.

```
(function(f){if(typeof exports==="object"&&typeof module!=="undefined"){module.exports=f()}else if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define([],f)}else{var g;if(typeof window!=="undefined"){g=window}else if(typeof global!=="undefined"){g=global}else if(typeof self!=="undefined"){g=self}else{g=this}g.channels = f()}})(function(){var define,module,exports;return (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
"use strict";
var isWebSocket = function (constructor) {
    return constructor && constructor.CLOSING === 2;
};
var isGlobalWebSocket = function () {
    return typeof WebSocket !== 'undefined' && isWebSocket(WebSocket);
};
var getDefaultOptions = function () { return ({
    constructor: isGlobalWebSocket() ? WebSocket : null,
    maxReconnectionDelay: 10000,
    minReconnectionDelay: 1500,
    reconnectionDelayGrowFactor: 1.3,
    connectionTimeout: 4000,
    maxRetries: Infinity,
    debug: false,
}); };
var bypassProperty = function (src, dst, name) {
    Object.defineProperty(dst, name, {
        get: function () { return src[name]; },
        set: function (value) { src[name] = value; },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
    });
};
var initReconnectionDelay = function (config) {
    return (config.minReconnectionDelay + Math.random() * config.minReconnectionDelay);
};
var updateReconnectionDelay = function (config, previousDelay) {
    var newDelay = previousDelay * config.reconnectionDelayGrowFactor;
    return (newDelay > config.maxReconnectionDelay)
        ? config.maxReconnectionDelay
        : newDelay;
};
var LEVEL_0_EVENTS = ['onopen', 'onclose', 'onmessage', 'onerror'];
var reassignEventListeners = function (ws, oldWs, listeners) {
    Object.keys(listeners).forEach(function (type) {
        listeners[type].forEach(function (_a) {
            var listener = _a[0], options = _a[1];
            ws.addEventListener(type, listener, options);
        });
    });
    if (oldWs) {
        LEVEL_0_EVENTS.forEach(function (name) { ws[name] = oldWs[name]; });
    }
};
var ReconnectingWebsocket = function (url, protocols, options) {
    var _this = this;
    if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
    var ws;
    var connectingTimeout;
    var reconnectDelay = 0;
    var retriesCount = 0;
    var shouldRetry = true;
    var savedOnClose = null;
    var listeners = {};
    // require new to construct
    if (!(this instanceof ReconnectingWebsocket)) {
        throw new TypeError("Failed to construct 'ReconnectingWebSocket': Please use the 'new' operator");
    }
    // Set config. Not using `Object.assign` because of IE11
    var config = getDefaultOptions();
    Object.keys(config)
        .filter(function (key) { return options.hasOwnProperty(key); })
        .forEach(function (key) { return config[key] = options[key]; });
    if (!isWebSocket(config.constructor)) {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid WebSocket constructor. Set `options.constructor`');
    }
    var log = config.debug ? function () {
        var params = [];
        for (var _i = 0; _i < arguments.length; _i++) {
            params[_i - 0] = arguments[_i];
        }
        return console.log.apply(console, ['RWS:'].concat(params));
    } : function () { };
    /**
     * Not using dispatchEvent, otherwise we must use a DOM Event object
     * Deferred because we want to handle the close event before this
     */
    var emitError = function (code, msg) { return setTimeout(function () {
        var err = new Error(msg);
        err.code = code;
        if (Array.isArray(listeners.error)) {
            listeners.error.forEach(function (_a) {
                var fn = _a[0];
                return fn(err);
            });
        }
        if (ws.onerror) {
            ws.onerror(err);
        }
    }, 0); };
    var handleClose = function () {
        log('close');
        retriesCount++;
        log('retries count:', retriesCount);
        if (retriesCount > config.maxRetries) {
            emitError('EHOSTDOWN', 'Too many failed connection attempts');
            return;
        }
        if (!reconnectDelay) {
            reconnectDelay = initReconnectionDelay(config);
        }
        else {
            reconnectDelay = updateReconnectionDelay(config, reconnectDelay);
        }
        log('reconnectDelay:', reconnectDelay);
        if (shouldRetry) {
            setTimeout(connect, reconnectDelay);
        }
    };
    var connect = function () {
        log('connect');
        var oldWs = ws;
        ws = new config.constructor(url, protocols);
        connectingTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            log('timeout');
            ws.close();
            emitError('ETIMEDOUT', 'Connection timeout');
        }, config.connectionTimeout);
        log('bypass properties');
        for (var key in ws) {
            // @todo move to constant
            if (['addEventListener', 'removeEventListener', 'close', 'send'].indexOf(key) < 0) {
                bypassProperty(ws, _this, key);
            }
        }
        ws.addEventListener('open', function () {
            clearTimeout(connectingTimeout);
            log('open');
            reconnectDelay = initReconnectionDelay(config);
            log('reconnectDelay:', reconnectDelay);
            retriesCount = 0;
        });
        ws.addEventListener('close', handleClose);
        reassignEventListeners(ws, oldWs, listeners);
        // because when closing with fastClose=true, it is saved and set to null to avoid double calls
        ws.onclose = ws.onclose || savedOnClose;
        savedOnClose = null;
    };
    log('init');
    connect();
    this.close = function (code, reason, _a) {
        if (code === void 0) { code = 1000; }
        if (reason === void 0) { reason = ''; }
        var _b = _a === void 0 ? {} : _a, _c = _b.keepClosed, keepClosed = _c === void 0 ? false : _c, _d = _b.fastClose, fastClose = _d === void 0 ? true : _d, _e = _b.delay, delay = _e === void 0 ? 0 : _e;
        if (delay) {
            reconnectDelay = delay;
        }
        shouldRetry = !keepClosed;
        ws.close(code, reason);
        if (fastClose) {
            var fakeCloseEvent_1 = {
                code: code,
                reason: reason,
                wasClean: true,
            };
            // execute close listeners soon with a fake closeEvent
            // and remove them from the WS instance so they
            // don't get fired on the real close.
            handleClose();
            ws.removeEventListener('close', handleClose);
            // run and remove level2
            if (Array.isArray(listeners.close)) {
                listeners.close.forEach(function (_a) {
                    var listener = _a[0], options = _a[1];
                    listener(fakeCloseEvent_1);
                    ws.removeEventListener('close', listener, options);
                });
            }
            // run and remove level0
            if (ws.onclose) {
                savedOnClose = ws.onclose;
                ws.onclose(fakeCloseEvent_1);
                ws.onclose = null;
            }
        }
    };
    this.send = function (data) {
        ws.send(data);
    };
    this.addEventListener = function (type, listener, options) {
        if (Array.isArray(listeners[type])) {
            if (!listeners[type].some(function (_a) {
                var l = _a[0];
                return l === listener;
            })) {
                listeners[type].push([listener, options]);
            }
        }
        else {
            listeners[type] = [[listener, options]];
        }
        ws.addEventListener(type, listener, options);
    };
    this.removeEventListener = function (type, listener, options) {
        if (Array.isArray(listeners[type])) {
            listeners[type] = listeners[type].filter(function (_a) {
                var l = _a[0];
                return l !== listener;
            });
        }
        ws.removeEventListener(type, listener, options);
    };
};
module.exports = ReconnectingWebsocket;

},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.WebSocketBridge = undefined;

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) { for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { var source = arguments[i]; for (var key in source) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) { target[key] = source[key]; } } } return target; };

var _createClass = function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ("value" in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; }();

var _reconnectingWebsocket = require('reconnecting-websocket');

var _reconnectingWebsocket2 = _interopRequireDefault(_reconnectingWebsocket);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

/**
 * Bridge between Channels and plain javascript.
 *
 * @example
 * const webSocketBridge = new WebSocketBridge();
 * webSocketBridge.connect();
 * webSocketBridge.listen(function(action, stream) {
 *   console.log(action, stream);
 * });
 */
var WebSocketBridge = function () {
  function WebSocketBridge(options) {
    _classCallCheck(this, WebSocketBridge);

    /**
     * The underlaying `ReconnectingWebSocket` instance.
     * 
     * @type {ReconnectingWebSocket}
     */
    this.socket = null;
    this.streams = {};
    this.default_cb = null;
    this.options = _extends({}, options);
  }

  /**
   * Connect to the websocket server
   *
   * @param      {String}  [url]     The url of the websocket. Defaults to
   * `window.location.host`
   * @param      {String[]|String}  [protocols] Optional string or array of protocols.
   * @param      {Object} options Object of options for [`reconnecting-websocket`](https://github.com/joewalnes/reconnecting-websocket#options-1).
   * @example
   * const webSocketBridge = new WebSocketBridge();
   * webSocketBridge.connect();
   */


  _createClass(WebSocketBridge, [{
    key: 'connect',
    value: function connect(url, protocols, options) {
      var _url = void 0;
      // Use wss:// if running on https://
      var scheme = window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws';
      var base_url = scheme + '://' + window.location.host;
      if (url === undefined) {
        _url = base_url;
      } else {
        // Support relative URLs
        if (url[0] == '/') {
          _url = '' + base_url + url;
        } else {
          _url = url;
        }
      }
      this.socket = new _reconnectingWebsocket2.default(_url, protocols, options);
    }

    /**
     * Starts listening for messages on the websocket, demultiplexing if necessary.
     *
     * @param      {Function}  [cb]         Callback to be execute when a message
     * arrives. The callback will receive `action` and `stream` parameters
     *
     * @example
     * const webSocketBridge = new WebSocketBridge();
     * webSocketBridge.connect();
     * webSocketBridge.listen(function(action, stream) {
     *   console.log(action, stream);
     * });
     */

  }, {
    key: 'listen',
    value: function listen(cb) {
      var _this = this;

      this.default_cb = cb;
      this.socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var action = void 0;
        var stream = void 0;

        if (msg.stream !== undefined) {
          action = msg.payload;
          stream = msg.stream;
          var stream_cb = _this.streams[stream];
          stream_cb ? stream_cb(action, stream) : null;
        } else {
          action = msg;
          stream = null;
          _this.default_cb ? _this.default_cb(action, stream) : null;
        }
      };
    }

    /**
     * Adds a 'stream handler' callback. Messages coming from the specified stream
     * will call the specified callback.
     *
     * @param      {String}    stream  The stream name
     * @param      {Function}  cb      Callback to be execute when a message
     * arrives. The callback will receive `action` and `stream` parameters.
      * @example
     * const webSocketBridge = new WebSocketBridge();
     * webSocketBridge.connect();
     * webSocketBridge.listen();
     * webSocketBridge.demultiplex('mystream', function(action, stream) {
     *   console.log(action, stream);
     * });
     * webSocketBridge.demultiplex('myotherstream', function(action, stream) {
     *   console.info(action, stream);
     * });
     */

  }, {
    key: 'demultiplex',
    value: function demultiplex(stream, cb) {
      this.streams[stream] = cb;
    }

    /**
     * Sends a message to the reply channel.
     *
     * @param      {Object}  msg     The message
     *
     * @example
     * webSocketBridge.send({prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value1'});
     */

  }, {
    key: 'send',
    value: function send(msg) {
      this.socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
    }

    /**
     * Returns an object to send messages to a specific stream
     *
     * @param      {String}  stream  The stream name
     * @return     {Object}  convenience object to send messages to `stream`.
     * @example
     * webSocketBridge.stream('mystream').send({prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value1'})
     */

  }, {
    key: 'stream',
    value: function stream(_stream) {
      var _this2 = this;

      return {
        send: function send(action) {
          var msg = {
            stream: _stream,
            payload: action
          };
          _this2.socket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
      };
    }
  }]);

  return WebSocketBridge;
}();

exports.WebSocketBridge = WebSocketBridge;

},{"reconnecting-websocket":1}]},{},[2])(2)
});
```